# Есть ли смысл подписывать приложение самодельным ключом?

Tags: windows, signature

Извините за глупый вопрос, но есть ли какой-то эффект от подписывания приложения самодельным ключом (без внесения в доверенные сертификаты) или это лишь четыре лишних килобайта? Антивирусы, полагаю, особого внимания на такой (да и на купленный, возможно) ключ не обратят, если только хуже не станет.

Comment: Только в качестве дополнительного контроля целостности и неизменённости разве что. Но тогда к подписанному файлу неплохо бы ещё выкладывать и сертификат своего ЦС.

Comment: Антивирусам на ваш сертификат будет поперек, если только вы не начнете им всякую мальварь подписывать.